# Compare two dates irrespective of time.

Tags: datetime, knockout.js, compare

I have to compare two dates in the following format,

```
User.ExpiryDate()
Wed Jun 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    __proto__: Invalid Date
dateToday
Wed Jun 01 2016 12:20:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    __proto__: Invalid Date
```

The result I am getting is wrong,

```
User.ExpiryDate() >= dateToday
false
```

**But it is true actually.**

It is getting wrong just because of time variation.

My questions are,

- How to compare these two dates irrespective of time ?
- How to get date alone with time 00.00.00 in new Date() ?

Any suggestion would be helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set time to 0.0.0.0 using `setHours()` in `date()`.

For example,

```
var DateToday = new date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

User.ExpiryDate() will be the date you mentioned. 
//Which is, 
Wed Jun 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    __proto__: Invalid Date
Now comparing this two will give TRUE.
User.ExpiryDate() >= dateToday
true
```

Now you can compare any dates without considering time.

Thanks!